# Seaborn hue not showing every values

Tags: dataframe, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, data-science

I'am trying to use Hue function from seaborn to auto select colors from a cmap, but when it comes to labelisation, it seems like seaborn doesn't found every value that should pass to hue= 'Target'

here is the code

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.relplot(data=data,x='Trial',y='Reaction_time',hue='Target')
plt.show()
```

For now, it only display 5 out of the 18 Target categories and I have no clue why.

[image]

Comment: Please add some reproducible test data to your post.

Comment: Did you try `legend='full'` to get a full legend? In order not to drown the plot with too much detail, by default, you get an abbreviated legend.

Comment: See [sns.relplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) for the `legend=` parameter: *If “brief”, numeric hue and size variables will be represented with a sample of evenly spaced values. If “full”, every group will get an entry in the legend. If “auto” (the default), choose between brief or full representation based on number of levels.*